# Can exercise strengthen tendons and ligaments?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

Is is possible to strengthen tendons using exercise to prevent injury, for example preventing shoulder dislocation?

Comment: I don't have the background to give a definitive answer, but it would make sense if especially tendons and maybe ligaments grow stronger through exercise... otherwise the risk of tendon damage should increase sharply as a function of muscle strength. I recall having heard/read somewhere that abusers of steroids have increased risk of tendon damage due to a too fast gain of muscle strength. Maybe someone can elaborate with a better answer.

Answer (score -1):

yes..It takes approximately 10 weeks of regular resistance exercise to strengthen your tendons, and it takes longer for them to thicken. You can expect up to 20 percent increase in strength and thickness of your ligaments and tendons with regular training.

Comment: Can you add some sources for your information? Unreferenced answers are frowned upon here.